# How do I stop Brahmins from coming into my structures in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

This might not sound like a big deal but it's driving me nuts. A number of my settlements have Brahmins wandering around inside buildings, getting in the way and generally making a nuisance of themselves.

An example is Hangman's Alley, which must be one of the smaller settlements but because of it's excellent position I've put a lot of effort into developing it. I've built a multi-story structure that's partially open on the ground floor (as the existing environment means I can't wall it up).

Every time I visit Hangman's Alley there is a Brahmin stomping around on the ground floor of my structure, blocking the stairwell, making it difficult to use the workbenches, standing on sleeping bags and generally getting in the way.

I then built a Brahmin drinking trough at the other end of the alley, and built a fence (with a gate) between the trough and the structure. But that hasn't changed anything, the Brahmin hasn't gone anywhere near the trough and was still blocking access to everywhere I want to be.

So I shot it, dead. Which sort of solved the problem - I could now get to the stairs/ use the workbenches - apart from the aesthetic issue of having an immovable dead two headed cow in my bedroom.

After a couple of game days adventuring I returned to Hangman's Alley to find the dead Brahmin had disappeared and there was now a live Brahmin back in the ground floor - blocking everything off. Argh!

I tried herding it by pushing/ hitting it (didn't work), I tried to build another fence - but space is very limited and I couldn't build a fence/ gate/ door system that'd allow me and the settlers access the structure while blocking the Brahmin. I've also seen Brahmins jammed in doorways/ entrance ways so I wasn't sure how effective a fence/ gate/ door would be if I could build one.

As I said, it probably doesn't seem like a big deal but it's driving me nuts. I haven't put hours into building my settlements to have noisy ugly two headed cows stomping around and blocking access to my bedroom/ storage/ workshop/ stairways. Not too mention the up close animation for Brahmins is pretty shonky with lots of clipping which makes the whole experience worse.

A few thoughts:

- Do I need to build a fenced enclosure around the trough?
- Do Brahmins automatically appear once a settlement reaches a certain population?
- Is there any way to make a settlement permanently Brahmin free?
- Do Brahmins need shelter or are they attracted by certain items?
- Am I losing my mind?

How do I stop Brahmins from coming into my structures in Fallout 4?

Comment: I'd be careful about shooting random Brahmin, especially if they've got a load on their back. They might belong to a trader that's visiting, and you probably don't want to piss them off.

Comment: @Iszi - noted, in this case the Brahmin isn't a pack animal. It's just mooching around and seems to be attached to the settlement rather than a NPC.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the fence so the brahmin has a clear path to the trough?  I notice that my brahmin likes to hang out next to it

Comment: @z - excellent idea. I'll try that. Except it doesn't explain why the second Brahmin didn't spawn next to the trough.

Comment: Make sure its a trough you built and not a normal bathtub. It should be staying near it if its a trough never seen one that ignores it.

Comment: @Nightmare - it's definitely a Brahmin trough.

Comment: Last night I accidentally meleed a Brahmin and the whole settlement turned hostile!

Comment: That is interesting Baron I have never seen a brahmin ignore a trough before. The whole purpose of that item is to keep the brahmins out of the way. Perhaps changing the location of it or just replacing it then waiting a couple hours would fix it.

Comment: @Nightmare - I think z might be onto something. I put a fence between the structure and the trough and opened the gate - expecting the Brahmin to walk through. But in hindsight they probably treat the gate as a solid fence. I'll remove the fence completely and see if it helps. Although I have had the problem with Brahmins in building in other settlements with easily accessible troughs far away from buildings.

Comment: just a thought, but have you tried building a brahmin feeding trough?

Comment: +1 for removing the fence/gate. I've found that even humanoid NPCs seem to get stuck on this. No matter where I put my bell, I can never seem to get everyone in Sanctuary to come to it because my food is grown inside a gate. Even during night-time hours - when nobody is working in the field - the path-finding logic just horribly fails around certain things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the purpose of the Brahmin Feed Trough, available under Resources > Miscellaneous.

As stated in game, Brahmin will tend to stay near their feed trough so if you place a feed trough away from entrances to buildings, all of your Brahmin will gather around it and not wander around the settlement anymore.

Here is a really bad example, where I placed the trough too close to a building and the Brahmin. However, it does demonstrate that the Brahmin will all try to get as close to the trough as possible:

[image: bad example]

If you build your trough in an enclosure away from buildings you'll generally find the Brahmin will enter the enclosure and stay there. This is demonstrated in the standard arrangement at Abernathy Farm:

[image: enclosure at Abernathy Farm]

Note this won't apply to Brahmin travelling with traders, they seem to do their own thing a lot.

Unfortunately you can't rely on settlers to close doors or gates, and there's nothing you can do to *make* them close without your intervention.

For Hangman's Alley specifically, it's quite a narrow space so if you walled off the other end of the alley and have the trough outside of the alley this would likely keep them away from your structures.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response but as I said in my question I've already installed a Brahmin feeding trough at the opposite end of Hangman's Alley. I didn't get on last night so didn't get a chance to test if already having the fence+open gate between the trough and the Brahmin is preventing it from using the trough.

Comment: You can try the trough with no barriers and see if the Brahmin will go near the trough.

Comment: It appears that Brahmin treat open gates as barriers so my issue was the open fence+open gate between the Brahmin and feed trough. It's interesting that the second Brahmin didn't spawn next to the feed trough after I killed the first one.